# OpenAPI3 and Swagger: How can I reference from one description of a component parameter to another?

Tags: swagger, openapi

How can I reference from one description of an component to another?

```
    comparam01:
      in: query
      name: comparam01
      schema:
        type: string
      description: |
        Any text.
    comparam02:
      in: query
      name: comparam02
      schema:
        # that's working!
        $ref: '#/components/parameters/comparam01/schema'
      description: 
        # Swagger says: Error (should be a string)
        $ref: '#/components/parameters/comparam01/description'
```

Comment: Can you clarify that the use case it? Do you need two identical parameters but with different `name`?

Comment: Yes, we have two identical parameters with different names. (And we would like to get rid of it, of course. But first we need it for the documentation.)

Comment: there is a bug in https://editor.swagger.io/, otherwise its working, when you see in right side result https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgNIx.png, it will show description of reference `comparam01` and when you implement in code its working properly, also i have checked in nodejs - swagger-ui-express npm its working.

Comment: @turivishal It's not a bug because the `description` keyword doesn't actually support `$ref`.

Comment: @helen you are right, checked in swagger specification it is support only string type, can you guide, why its working in code side, and not giving any error or warning, and also it show in editor UI side, also i have used in my past project.

Comment: @helen it used to work w/o any error a few days ago.